# Embeding Part of SSRS Report on body and attach excel file in the same email subscription

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssis, reporting

I want to have one SSRS subscription with Table A in the email body and table B in the excel attachment.

How can I do this using SSRS or SSIS or SQL? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @PeterSchneider I developed script using  HTML body to embed it into email body. I send the email using sp_send_dbmail along with attachment. do you have alternative way of accomplishing this ? thanks